# Converting complex integrals to analytic expressions

Tags: integration

I have the following formula:
$$
u\left( \rho ,\beta \right) =\int_0^{2\pi}{\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-w^2r^2}e^{il\theta}e^{-ir\rho \cos \left( \theta -\beta \right)}r}drd\theta}
$$
At first thought, I wanted to try solving it directly through mathematica software, but I found that I could not get the analytical result directly.
[image]

Therefore, I would like to know if it is possible to solve the analytic expression by transforming it with some special functions in math (e.g., Bessel functions) and so on.

Here I have a reference result, but no guarantee of its correctness.
$$
u\left( \rho ,\beta \right) =i^{-l}\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{2w^2}e^{il\beta}e^{-\frac{\rho ^2}{8w^2}}\frac{\rho}{2w}\left[ I_{\frac{l-1}{2}}\left( \frac{\rho ^2}{8w^2} \right) -I_{\frac{l+1}{2}}\left( \frac{\rho ^2}{8w^2} \right) \right] 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is actually not difficult. First, by rotating the coordinate system, so that $\theta - \beta \mapsto \theta$, then

\begin{align}
u(\rho,\beta) &= \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\omega^2 r^2}\mathrm{e}^{i\ell\theta} \mathrm{e}^{-ir\rho\cos(\theta-\beta)} r\, \mathrm{d}r\\[.2cm]
&=\mathrm{e}^{i\ell \beta}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\omega^2 r^2}r\mathrm{d}r \int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{i\ell \theta} \mathrm{e}^{-ir \rho \cos \theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align}
We can first integrate $\theta$ and use the well-known [integral representation of Bessel function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9):

$$
\color{royalblue}{J_n(z) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(z\sin\theta-n\theta)\, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{i^{-n}}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\mathrm{e}^{iz\cos \theta}\cos n\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta}
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus we find,
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{i\ell \theta}\mathrm{e}^{-ir\rho\cos\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta &= \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-ir\rho\cos\theta} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\ell\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\ell\theta}}{2}\, \mathrm{d}\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-ir\rho\cos\theta} \cos \ell \theta\, \mathrm{d}\theta\\[.2cm]
&=2\pi i^{\ell} J_{\ell}(-r\rho)
\end{align}
**Therefore, the OP’s question needs to add a restriction that $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$.** So,
\begin{align}
u(\rho,\beta) &= 2\pi \mathrm{e}^{i\ell \beta} i^{\ell} \int_0^{\infty} r \mathrm{e}^{-\omega^2 r^2} J_{\ell}(-r\rho) \, \mathrm{d}r , \quad r^2 \mapsto x\\[.2cm]
&=\pi i^{-\ell} \mathrm{e}^{i\ell\beta} \int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\omega^2 x}J_{\ell}(\rho\sqrt{x})\, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
You can substitute the series expression of the Bessel function of the first kind, then integrate it term by term, and then compare it with the series expression of the modified Bessel function, you can get the following results:
$$
\color{royalblue}{\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x}J_{\nu}(b\sqrt{x})\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{b}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha^3}}\exp \left(-\frac{b^2}{8\alpha}\right) \left[I_{\frac{1}{2}(\nu-1)}\left(\frac{b^2}{8\alpha}\right) - I_{\frac{1}{2}(\nu+1)}\left(\frac{b^2}{8\alpha}\right)\right]} 
$$
Finally,
\begin{align}\color{red}{
u(\rho,\beta) = i^{-\ell} \frac{\rho}{4} \frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\omega^3} \mathrm{e}^{i\ell\beta} \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{\rho^2}{8\omega^2}} \left[I_{\frac{\ell-1}{2}} \left(\frac{\rho^2}{8\omega^2} \right) - I_{\frac{\ell+1}{2}} \left(\frac{\rho^2}{8\omega^2} \right)\right]}
\end{align}
This is consistent with the answer provided by the OP.